# Strange Typescript inheritance on Angular 2 Guide Tutorial DI

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection

In the [Angular 2 guide Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) (in the first chapter *Why dependency injection?*) there are some strange lines of code. They work, but I don't know why. You can also find the running example on https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/dependency-injection/ts/eplnkr.html.

In the file **car.ts** the **class Engine** and the **class Car** are declared as:

```
export class Engine { 
  public cylinders = 4; 
}

export class Car {
  public description = 'DI';

  constructor(public engine: Engine, public tires: Tires) { }
  ...
}
```

In the file **car-creation.ts** the class Car is used ...

```
import { Car, Engine, Tires } from './car';

class Engine2 {
  constructor(public cylinders: number) { }
}

export function superCar() {
  // Super car with 12 cylinders and Flintstone tires.
  let bigCylinders = 12;
  let car = new Car(new Engine2(bigCylinders), new Tires());
  car.description = 'Super';
  return car;
}
```

It works without warnings or errors by the Typescript compiler.

Strange! Why it is possible to create car with a wrong engine type?
`new Engine2(...)` creates an object from class Engine2 which is not derived from class Engine.

Is this behavior a bug or a feature of Typescript?

I would expect the following lines of code in the file **car-creation.ts**.

```
class Engine2 extends Engine {
  constructor(public cylinders: number) {
    super();
  }
}
```

... or ...

```
class Engine2 extends Engine {
  constructor(cylinders: number) {
    super(); 
    this.cylinders = cylinders;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript uses *structural typing* instead of nominal typing. You can find more on the topic [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). Even though you're writing `class` it is not a ... class in the sense of class-inheritance. It's just syntax sugar for creating a [Prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

```
class Engine2 {
  constructor(public cylinders: number) { }
}

class Engine { 
  public cylinders = 4; 
}
```

Even though they do not inherit from each other, they a the same on a structural level. Both have a `public` member `cylinders` that is a `number`. While `Engine` will always have 4 cylinders, you can init `Engine2` with any number of cylinders.

Writing the constructor like `constructor(public cylinders: number) {}` is syntax sugar for initializing a public member.